# android:layout_below= Does Not Set TextViews Below ImageButtons in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm not sure why but in my `linearlayout`    `android:layout_below=` Does Not Set `TextViews` Below `ImageButtons`.

I know I've overlooked something but I'm not sure exactly what that might be.

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/photos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/photos" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/photos"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/audio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/audio" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/audio"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/written"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/written" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/written"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/video" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/video"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="800dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_e" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_below` is for `RelativeLayout` not for `LinearLayout`. You can use `RelativeLayout` no need for `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

`android:layout_below` is only for `RelativeLayout` not for `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/photos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/photos" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/audio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/audio" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/written"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/written" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/video" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_e" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_below only works inside the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `RalativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

`LinearLayout` can not allow layout_below property.

Answer (score 0):

Put each related `ImageButton` and `TextView` into another `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` as follows...

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/photos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photos"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

So, your updated layout can be as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/photos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/photos" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/audio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/audio" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/written"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/written" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/video" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_e" />

</RelativeLayout>
```